# Получить список PCI устройств на шине локального компьютера

Tags: c#, драйвер

Как получить список pci устройств своего компьютера ? Сгодится любой способ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Под Windows через WMI можно.

Comment: Как составить запрос для обращения WMI?  Где это подробно и понятно описывается (желательно на русском) ?

Comment: Начните с этой статьи - http://sysadminblog.ru/code/2011/02/28/c-sbor-informacii-o-kompyutere-1.html

Все классы WMI на msdn - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394554(v=vs.85).aspx